# Update PostgreSQL columns with random numbers according to a uniform or normal law

Tags: postgresql, random, sql-update

## Context

I have a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) (v.10.12) table which contains several hundreds of thousands of rows and many columns.

**Short**: I'd like to initialize random values in some columns according to either a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) or a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

### Uniform distribution

I have 3 empty columns which I'd like to initialize with **uniform** random numbers (i.e. according to a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) along each column).

For that, I'm using the PostgreSQL `random()` function, but it is not clearly explained in the documentation whether the generated numbers are picked from a uniform or a normal distribution:

[image: PostgreSQL (unclear) documentation for the random function]
Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-math.html

So I made the (I hope correct) hypothesis it is a uniform distribution from now.

### Normal distribution

And I have 3 other empty columns, which I'd like to initialize with **normal** random numbers (i.e. according to a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) along each column):

[image: Normal distribution for each of the 3 columns]

## Results

### For a uniform distribution

I did this (I actually figured it out while writing this post);

```
UPDATE schema.tables
     SET col1 = (1 * random() + 1)::float4,
     col2 = (1 * random() + 1)::float4,
     col3 = (1 * random() + 1)::float4
```

Which is a bit slow but seems to work, because here is an example of generated data:

[image: 3 columns of uniform random number]

And the data histogram for one column is almost uniform, so I guess it's OK:

[image: Example of a uniform distribution across one column]

But what would be great is to set the entire columns values in one shot instead of row by row (or maybe this row-by-row way of updating the table performs really better in SQL. I don't know, but it's more a linear algebra reasoning that I have in the background).

### For a normal distribution

I'm stuck with the following query, inspired by the previous one but using the `normal_rand` function from the [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tablefunc.html) extension:

```
UPDATE schema.table
  SET col1 = (1 * normal_rand(1,50.0,20.0) + 2)::float4),
  col2 = (1 * normal_rand(1,50.0,20.0) + 2)::float4),
  col3 = (1 * normal_rand(1,50.0,20.0) + 2)::float4),
```

but here, I am facing the following error: `set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE`.

So, I guessed I have to use a `SELECT` sub-query then, hence I also tried this, but without much success:

```
UPDATE schema.table
  SET col1 = sub.col
  FROM (SELECT (1 * normal_rand(1, 50.0, 20.0) + 2)::float4 as col) AS sub,
  col2 = sub.col
  FROM (SELECT (1 * normal_rand(1, 50.0, 10.0) + 2)::float4 as col) AS sub,
  col3 = sub.col
  FROM (SELECT (1 * normal_rand(1, 50.0, 5.0) + 2)::float4 as col) AS sub
```

Where I get a `syntax error at or near col2`

But If I play with one single column:

```
UPDATE schema.table
  SET col1 = sub.col
  FROM (SELECT (1 * normal_rand(1, 50.0, 20.0) + 2)::float4 as col) AS sub;
```

It almost works, the query is successful, but I have the exact same number in each row of the column, which obviously doesn't make it a normal distribution!

So my dream would be to be able to update all **whole** column in one shot, using something such as:

```
UPDATE schema.table 
SET col1 = sub.col 
FROM (
    SELECT (
        1 * normal_rand(
            SELECT count(*) FROM schema.table, 
            50.0, 
            20.0
            ) + 2
    ):: float4 AS col
) AS sub;
```

But here again, I got a syntax error at the 2nd SELECT position; `syntax error at or near "select"`

## Question

How can I set one or more entire column(s) with random numbers according to a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

In a pinch, you can try the following solution:

```
((random() + random() + random() + random() + random() + random() + random() + random() + random() + random() + random() + random()) - 6)
```

The idiom above uses twelve `random()` calls to generate a random variate that approximates a standard normal distribution (mean of 0 and standard deviation 1), and takes advantage of the central limit theorem.  It's an approximation in part because the random variate generated this way won't be less than -6 or greater than 6, whereas the normal distribution can theoretically take on any real number; however numbers less than -6 or greater than 6 occur so rarely (about 1 in 500 million) that it may be negligible in your case.